# How do I change the background of visualforce page for page 1 and the rest

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, html

I have a visualforce page document for which I want to place an full width image on the firstpage and on the rest of the document no image.

I tried the following down below but all the pages get a background. If I give the body of the firstpage a background I end up with an image cropped by the margins.

Is ther a way to define page 1 in @page CSS

Current Example:

```
 <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page {
            margin-top: 20%;  
            margin-bottom:13%;
            margin-right: 10%;
            margin-left:7%;
            size: A4;
            background-image:url({!$Resource.Voorblad}) ;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size: 120% 120% !important;

            @top-right {
            content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-right{
            content: element(footer);
            }
            }
            div.header {
            align:left;
            padding: 0px;
            position: running(header);
            }
            body{
            margin-left:0%;
            font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:90%;
            }     
            div.footer {
            height: 250px;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            position: running(footer);
            margin:-2em -1em -12em;
            font-size:60%;
            color:#21789e;
            text-align: right;
            line-height:120%;
            }
            div.header {
            position: running(header);
            }
            .pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
            }
            .pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
            }
            table {border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 0;
            margin-top:5px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            }
            td{vertical-align:top;
            padding-left:
            0px;
            }
            table.details td {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            padding-left:5px;
            }
            .backgroundimg {
            background-image:url({!$Resource.backgroundtable}) ;
            background-size: 300px 100px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

Comment: Disable standard style sheet, turn of lf html and body tag with page attribute, and add your own in html.should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this adding a  @page :first definition the following way:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
                @page {
                margin-top: 20%;  
                margin-bottom:13%;
                margin-right: 10%;
                margin-left:7%;
                size: A4;

                @top-right {
                content: element(header);
                }
                @bottom-right{
                content: element(footer);
                }
                }
                div.header {
                align:left;
                padding: 0px;
                position: running(header);
                }
                body{
                margin-left:0%;
                font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size:90%;
                }     
                div.footer {
                height: 250px;
                display: block;
                padding: 5px;
                position: running(footer);
                margin:-2em -1em -12em;
                font-size:100%;
                color:#000000;
                text-align: right;
                line-height:120%;
                }
                div.header {
                position: running(header);
                }
                .pagenumber:before {
                content: counter(page);
                }
                .pagecount:before {
                content: counter(pages);
                }
                table {border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 0;
                margin-top:5px;
                margin-bottom:20px;
                }
                td{vertical-align:top;
                padding-left:
                0px;
                }
                table.details td {
                border: 2px solid #000;
                padding-left:5px;
                }
                .backgroundimg {
                background-image:url({!$Resource.backgroundtable}) ;
                background-size: 300px 100px;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                }
                @page :first {
                background-image:url({!$Resource.youresource}) ;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size: 120% 120% !important;
                @bottom-right {
                }
                @top-right {
                }
                }
            </style>
```